# how to create half star rating widget in ionic app?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have an ionic app in which i have enabled the option for the user to give rating. I use `ionic-rating` tool for that. But it does not give the option to give half star rating. so how can I implement half star rating in my ionic app.

Comment: may have a look at this `http://market.ionic.io/plugins/ionicratings`

Answer (score 0):

update your framework try this https://github.com/fraserxu/ionic-rating

Comment: i already use this and it only displays half star but did not give the ability to give half stars.

Comment: this example are just for showing half star rating I want to make something by which I can give half star rating.

Comment: i see, i think you cant do that with ionic framework.